# Lightning out authentication for website VS mobile App

Tags: lightning-out

I am creating a Lightning Out Component(LOC) that will be used in website XYZ available after login to that website. So i am a website XYZ user and I have logged in and the LOC is now visible to me. My assumption is that I, the user do not need a Salesforce user. The website server will be the authenticated Salesforce user who's session id would be used to displaying the content to the XYZ user.
Does this make sense?
So if i host my LOC in a mobile app, can the same thing be achieved? Can the apps server be authenticated on Salesforce and these credentials used in the LOC?

Thanks for you help.